# How do I get started with mastercoin? What tutorial or guide is a good start?

Tags: omni, altcoin-development

How do I get started with Mastercoin? Are there useful tutorials or guides? I am looking at creating a cryptocurrency on Mastercoin so as to leverage on the features of the Bitcoin blockchain and Mastercoin.